# uploads some file with filetransfer/cordova-plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I would like uploads many image with the cordova-plugin Filetransfer. I searched on google, documentation,forum but i don't find it. So, i hope that your will help to find solution.

Comment: You should mark some answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

it will help you
[Multiupload Cordova](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/multiupload)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it from here.. This might be a help.

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/08/10/processing-multiple-simultaneous-uploads-with-cordova/

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot but the problem is that the server receive the file one by one. I would like that the server receive a array of image as in html